# Where does the default datasource url for h2 come from on Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I started a new spring-boot 1.5.3 project. Added some starters:

- data-jpa
- starter-web
- data-rest

And then added

- devtools
- h2

I can see the datasource is automatically set to `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`. Everything is working fine but just out of curiosity I tried to determine from where the `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` value comes from. I searched spring-boot, spring-data, spring jdbc and devtools projects' source code but I was unable to find out. As far as I can tell, the value does not come as default suggestion from h2 either.

So where does this value exactly come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be coming from this class, which also contains the defaults for other flavours of in-mem DBs.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java

`H2(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2, "org.h2.Driver", "jdbc:h2:mem:%s;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"),`

Which get's loaded via, the DataSourceAutoConfiguration if it meets the criteria,

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java

The default for the database name, `testdb`, comes from a default set in the Datasourceproperties,

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java

`private String name = "testdb";`

Comment: That's a complete, precise, exactly what I was looking for answer. Thank you very much Darren! As I beginner on Spring I'll try to improve documentation on this.

Comment: As of Version 2.3.3 you find "testdb" in: public String determineDatabaseName()