# In Spring Boot what tells the app to use a database?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I've a small Spring Boot project into which Maven pulls

- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
- spring-boot-starter-data-rest
- h2

and others.  I don't have any DataSource references, but does have JpaRepository and a UserDetailsService.

How, then, is are Spring libraries deciding to use Hibernate (shows up logged in the console) and, I guess, H2?

I looked at this [stackoverflow conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446597/where-does-the-default-datasource-url-for-h2-come-from-on-spring-boot) but my own console log has no "h2" or "database" log statements.

Comment: Spring Boot auto-configures a number of things for you.  If you specify a data source in the properties files, it will know how to instantiate the necessary components.  See more on the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html - In the case of H2, you don't even need to do that much. 
 From the docs **Spring Boot can auto-configure embedded H2, HSQL and Derby databases. You don’t need to provide any connection URLs, simply include a build dependency to the embedded database that you want to use.**

Answer (score 0):

you should add "schema.sql" into src/main/resource. It must match your entity classes. spring boot will take care of the rest.
also you better write this into your application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=create-drop
```

You can also work with MySQL instead of h2. delete h2 dependency, add mysql connector dependency and add these to application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```