# How does springboot JPA knows which database will be used?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I got to know Java spring JPA a couple days ago and there is one question which really makes me confused.

As I create a repository and use 'save()' method to save some objects into it. How does it know what type of database I am using and which local location to save.

I know I can config database (h2) like:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem/mydb

Then JPA will know: ok you are using h2 database and url is "jdbc:h2:mem/mydb"

However, some people said this config is not mandatory. If without this config, how does JPA knows which database I gonna use?

Comment: You have to provide a config. There is no magic :)

Comment: @Tushar There is no error logs shown in console If I comment out that config. But maybe you are right, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the spring-boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html):

> You should at least specify the URL by setting the spring.datasource.url property. Otherwise, Spring Boot tries to auto-configure an embedded database.

The following class is responsible for providing default settings for embedded DB: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java#L302)

```java
public String determineDatabaseName() {
        ...
        if (this.embeddedDatabaseConnection != EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.NONE) {
            return "testdb";
        }
        ...
    }
```

This answer can also be helpful: [Where does the default datasource url for h2 come from on Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446597/where-does-the-default-datasource-url-for-h2-come-from-on-spring-boot/44446776#44446776)